# Como usar o scanner do Java

Tags: java, scanner

Estava fazendo um exercício para a universidade utilizando a classe `Scanner` e aconteceu algo inusitado, observem o código.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 11; i ++){
  //problema(esta pulando a escolha de um dos jogadores, precisamente o jogador 1)
  System.out.println(P[i]);
  System.out.println("Jogador 1, faça a sua aposta:");
  aposta1 = leitor.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Jogador 2, faça a sua aposta:");
  aposta2 = leitor.nextInt();   
  System.out.println("Jogador 1, insira a sua resposta:");
  resposta1 = leitor.nextLine();  
  System.out.println("Jogador 2, insira a sua resposta:");
  resposta2 = leitor.nextLine();
```

Este código deveria aceitar a respostas dos dois jogadores, mas veja a saída do programa:

```
Quanto é 2 + 2?
A- 1
B- 2
C- 3
D- 4
Jogador 1, faça a sua aposta:
10
Jogador 2, faça a sua aposta:
10
Jogador 1, insira a sua resposta:
Jogador 2, insira a sua resposta:
D
O jogador 1 errou
O Jogador 2 acertou
```

Como vocês podem observar, o programa pula o leitor da `resposta1` não permitindo eu colocar uma resposta, retornando como vazio. Este tipo de problema só aconteceu depois que eu inseri os leitores do `aposta1` e `aposta2`, quando os mesmos são retirados os leitores do `resposta1` e `resposta2` são lidos normalmente.

Como solução eu criei outra classe `Scanner` para as `resposta1` e `resposta2` separando os leitores, que no final deu certo. Porém eu fiquei curioso a respeito do porque o leitor da erro ao ser usado múltiplas vezes

Comment: Pela descrição de uso do método, me pareceu que ele avança uma linha de código e para na próxima utilização do Scanner. Essa seria a minha explicação, não sei se está certa.Tente utilizar `leitor.next();`, pelo menos para mim funcionou.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

É por causa do `ENTER` que você da quando lê o inteiro.

**UPDATE:** me enganei, troquei `nextLine()` por `readLine()`. Já está corrigido.

O `ENTER` produz uma string `\n` que é consumido pelo próximo comando `nextLine()`. Você teria que colocar mais um `nextLine()` para ler esse `\n`, ou seja, dois `nextLine()` seguidos, um para consumir o `\n` e outro para ler a resposta do usuário.

Comment: É isso mesmo Earendul, mas para utilizar `nextLine();` para a segunda resposta, deve se usar somente uma vez.

Comment: Muito obrigado aos dois, ambas as soluções resolveram o problema. Agradeço o tempo de vocês o/ . Eu até gostaria de votar positivo, mas eu não tenho reputação suficiente.

Comment: Raul, ainda não acabou :) Dê a questão como encerrada dando a melhor resposta para a resposta do Earendul, já que só comentei a sua pergunta

Comment: Para isso é só clicar no botão embaixo da votação? Sou novato xD

Answer (score 19):

A resposta do @Earendul já aponta o motivo correto pelo qual o erro ocorre, entretanto existe outra a solução ao que ele propõe.

Explicando o erro com minhas próprias palavras, quando você usa o comando `nextInt();` você está lendo o próximo inteiro, entretanto não está lendo a linha inteira, e na linha inteira existe algo a mais do que apenas o inteiro que você digitou.

Faça o seguinte teste que ficará mais claro para você, ao invés de digitar `10`, `ENTER`, `10`, `ENTER`, faça assim, `10 10 D`, `ENTER`, `D`, `ENTER`. Ou seja, digite duas vezes o 10 e já digite a resposta do jogador 1, assim que o programa estiver aguardando logo a primeira entrada. O programa irá ler o primeiro 10 e o atribuirá a `aposta1` por causa do `nextInt()`, lerá o segundo 10 e o atribuirá ao `aposta2` por causa do outro `nextInt()`, lerá o restante da linha por causa do comando `nextLine()` e atribuirá a `resposta1` e então aguardará pela entrada da `resposta2`, que também será `D`.

Assim seria um dos meios corretos de entrar os dados no seu programa do jeito que ele está, entretanto sabemos que não que é isso que você quer, o correto seria corrigir o seu programa para que ele fique mais intuitivo para o usuário.

Uma possível solução:

Não use `nextInt()`, use `leitor.nextLine();`, verifique se o input é um inteiro e daí converta para int com o comando `Integer.parseInt()`

Inclusive, assim você estará tornando seu programa resistente a entradas inválidas quando for solicitado entrar com um inteiro, pois do jeito que está se você digitar um caracter no lugar de um inteiro uma exceção será lançada na cara do usuário, e o ideal seria você tratá-la e apresentar uma mensagem de erro mais amigável, do que um monte de código incompreensível para não programadores.

Comment: Tambem percebi isso com o método `leitor.next()`.
Se for `String`, por exemplo, ele preencherá com até o primeiro "espaço"

Comment: Opa vlw pela explicação e pela ajuda!