# Comparable e Arrays.Sort

Tags: java

Estou tendo dificuldades na utilização da interface comparable, devo realizar a comparação crescente de pilotos de acordo com a pontuação deles (classe `PilotoEquipe`), e então na classe `CorridaX1`, preciso utilizar o `Arrays.sort` para organizar o array de pilotos. Ao rodar o `Arrays.sort` recebo o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:316)
>     at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:184)     at
>   java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1246)   at
>   LeonardoBruksch.CorridaX1.orderna(CorridaX1.java:41)  at
>   LeonardoBruksch.ControleFederacao.main(ControleFederacao.java:35) Java
>   Result: 1

Classe PilotoEquipe:

```
public class PilotoEquipe implements PilotoEquipeInterface, Comparable<PilotoEquipe>{
    protected String nome;
    protected String equipe;
    protected double pontos;

    public PilotoEquipe(String nome, String equipe, double pontos){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.equipe = equipe;
        this.pontos = pontos;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    @Override
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public String getEquipe() {
        return equipe;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEquipe(String equipe) {
        this.equipe = equipe;
    }

    @Override
    public double getPontos() {
        return pontos;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPontos(double pontos) {
        this.pontos = pontos;
    }

    public int compareTo(PilotoEquipe piloto) {
        if(this.getPontos() > piloto.getPontos())
            return -1;
        else if(this.getPontos() == piloto.getPontos())
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Classe CorridaX1:

```
public class CorridaX1 {
    PilotoEquipeInterface[] p = new PilotoEquipeInterface[20];

    public void exibePilotos(){
        int i = 0;
        while(p[i] != null && i<p.length){
            int numero = i+1;
            System.out.println("Piloto "+numero+":");
            System.out.println("Nome: "+p[i].getNome());
            System.out.println("Equipe: "+p[i].getEquipe());
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
            i++;
        }
    }

    public void orderna(){
        Arrays.sort(p);
    }
}
```

Classe ControleFederacao(main)

```
public class ControleFederacao {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 

        CorridaX1 c = new CorridaX1();

            System.out.println("Digite o nome: ");
            String nome = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Digite a equipe: ");
            String equipe = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Digite os pontos do piloto: ");
            double pontos = scanner.nextDouble();

            PilotoEquipe piloto = new PilotoEquipe(nome, equipe, pontos);
            c.p[0] = piloto;


        System.out.println("Antes da Ordenacao: ");
        c.exibePilotos();

        System.out.println("Apos a Ordenacao: ");
        c.orderna();
        c.exibePilotos();
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque o conteúdo da classe ControleFederacao.java e onde é a linha 35 para que possamos lhe ajudar. Por ser NullPointer, acredito que erro seja simples.

Comment: O erro está na lógica dentro do seu método main, na classe ControleFederacao. Por favor, clique em [edit] e adicione o código dessa classe para que seja possível ajudarmos.

Comment: Cuidado ao instanciar esse array de 20 posições, se deixar alguma posição não preenchida vai causar esse NPE. Se a quantidade de objetos da classe `PilotoEquipeInterface` é dinâmica use um `ArrayList` por exemplo.

Comment: Como já dito, muito provavelmente seu problema são posições nulas no array (já que o erro se dá no próprio `sort`, e não no seu código). E gostaria de complementar com um detalhe: evite retornar `0` no `compareTo` a menos que os objetos sejam de fato iguais (i.e. `a.equals(b)` retorne `true`). No seu caso isso não é tão importante, pois você só está usando o método `sort`, mas se você usasse esses objetos como chave de um `TreeSet`, `TreeMap` ou similar esse comportamento (inconsistência entre o `compareTo` e o `equals`) causaria problemas. Escolha um "critério de desempate"...

Comment: Coloquei a minha classe main(ControleFederacao) ali em cima também! Valeu ai galera!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontrei três problemas no seu código, o primeiro está na classe CorridaX1. Quando você faz:

```
while(p[i] != null && i<p.length){
```

Você está propenso a receber um `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, pois você primeiro tenta acessar um elemento no array `p`, e depois você verifica se o `i` ainda representa um índice de elemento válido dentro do seu vetor `p`, dessa forma você pode tentar acessar um elemento de `p` além do quantidade máxima que ele suporta. Troque essa linha pelo código abaixo que você estará livre desse problema:

```
while(i<p.length && p[i] != null){
```

O segundo problema, é o que origina o seu `NullPointerException`. Você cria um vetor de vinte posições do tipo PilotoEquipeInterface, entretanto você cria apenas um único objeto do tipo PilotoEquipe, e deixa as outras dezenove posições do vetor referenciando nulo. Em seguida você chama o método `sort()`, quando ele tenta ordenar o vetor ele se depara com alguma referências nulas e então você recebe a exceção.

Você possivelmente cometeu esse equívoco pois quis fazer um teste de inserir apenas um elemento antes de criar seu laço de repetição, portanto uma possível solução é fazer com que sua variável de referência `p` tenha referências válidas para objetos do tipo PilotoEquipe.

O terceiro problema, é que você usa um `nextDouble()` para ler os pontos, entretanto você:

1) Não tem certeza de que o usuário entrará com um double quando lhe for solicitado;

2) Se o usuário digitar um double, você estará ignorando o resta da linha, que possui um caracter `\n`, que foi produzido ao pressionar o <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Você deve tratá-lo, caso contrário você não conseguirá entrar com o nome do próximo piloto.

Duas possíveis soluções:

```
    for(int i=0; i<c.p.length; i++) { //o for elimina o primeiro e o segundo problemas
        System.out.println("Digite o nome: ");
        String nome = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Digite a equipe: ");
        String equipe = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Digite os pontos do piloto: ");
        double pontos = scanner.nextDouble();
        scanner.nextLine(); //uma solução rápida para o terceiro problema

        PilotoEquipe piloto = new PilotoEquipe(nome, equipe, pontos);
        c.p[i] = piloto;
    }
```

Ou da forma que eu prefiro:

```
    for(int i=0; i<c.p.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Digite o nome: ");
        String nome = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Digite a equipe: ");
        String equipe = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Digite os pontos do piloto: ");
        String linha = scanner.nextLine();
        double pontos;
        try {
            pontos = Double.parseDouble(linha);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //aqui você pode atribuir um valor padrão para os pontos
            /* Exemplo
            pontos=1.0;
            */
            //ou interromper o programa com uma mensagem de erro
            /* Exemplo
            System.out.println("Valor inválido para pontos");
            return;
            */
            //ou então insistir até que o usuário entre com um double para os pontos
        }

        PilotoEquipe piloto = new PilotoEquipe(nome, equipe, pontos);
        c.p[i] = piloto;
    }
```

Pergunta relacionada que pode te ajudar a entender o terceiro problema:

[Como usar o scanner do Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30642/3117)