# Como imprimir itens selecionado?

Tags: java

```
while(resposta == "sim"){
            System.out.println("Informe o Numero do Produto desejado");
            System.out.println("15 - Parafuso, 20 - Porca, 30 - Arruela");
            cod_peca = scn.nextInt();

                switch(cod_peca){
                    case 15:
                        System.out.println("Voce selecionou Parafuso");
                        break;
                    case 20:
                        System.out.println("Voce selecionou Porca");
                        break;
                    case 30:
                        System.out.println("Voce selecionou Arruela");
                        break;
                }
            System.out.println("Informe a Quantidade do Produto");
            qtdeProd = scn.nextInt();
        }
System.out.println("Numero do Produto comprado: "+cod_peca);
```

Comment: Qual o problema em concreto que está a encontrar? Tente ser um pouco mais especifico no que não está a funcionar, e de como queria que estivesse a funcionar

Comment: Me desculpe, entrei  aqui hoje e estou postando aqui pela primeira vez. Meio perdido ainda kkk enfim, estou para ler 3 produtos e que a pessoa selecione apenas os produtos selecionado e que o imprima. Eu nao sei, a opcao seria fazer por switch case ou por if else.  poderia me dar um help?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Entrada não executada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101036/entrada-n%c3%a3o-executada)

Comment: Uma coisa é que comparação de `String` se faz com `equals`: `"sim".equals(resposta)`

Comment: vlw galera! deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Só há um pequeno problema que faz com que o Compilador não compile. O operador `==` serve apenas para comparar números no Java (ex.: `2 == 4`, `5 == 5`; já `3 == "ola"` não), mas em outras linguagens como Python serve para comparar `números` e `strings`.

Para comparar `strings` com `números` ou `strings` com `strings` não usamos `==` no Java, mas usamos **equals** `resposta.equals("sim");`

Faça isso que o programa vai rodar.

Comment: Obrigado! deu certo!