# Como utilizar o Scanner para capturar entradas vindas do teclado?

Tags: java, entrada-de-dados

Gostaria saber como utilizar o `Scanner` no `java` para simular `cin` e `cout` do c++

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Utilizando o [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) você pode capturar entrada de dados utilizando os métodos abaixo, que são os mais comuns:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

s.nextInt();
s.nextDouble(); 
s.nextFloat(); 
s.next(); //captura como string mas se o trecho tiver espaço, ignora o que
          //estiver após o espaço. Não move o scanner pra linha seguinte
s.nextLine();// captura como string uma linha inteira e para após uma quebra
             //de linha, move o scanner para a linha seguinte
```

Você só precisa tomar cuidado ao utilizar capturas de tipos primitivos com capturas de String, por causa do vazamento da **[quebra de linha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30642/como-usar-o-scanner-do-java?rq=1)**.

E para saída de dados, o java tem o `System.out.println()` que exibe informação inserindo uma quebra de linha, e o `System.out.print()` que faz a mesma coisa, só que sem a quebra de linha.

Comment: qual método para não pegar lixo de memória  ?

Comment: @Rodolfo O problema ocorre ao fazer uma captura usando `nextLine()` logo após a captura de um tipo primitivo, mas você pode pegar o linebreak dando um `s.nextLine()` antes de fazer a proxima captura de String.  O @Math dá outra sugestão bem bacana [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30642/como-usar-o-scanner-do-java?rq=1),