# Como fazer a instrução if-else funcionar para leitura de números inteiros

Tags: java

O meu programa compilou em cmd, mas ao correr não executa a instrução `if`, mostrando apenas a última `String` e fecha. Pretendo que o utilizador possa ter a opção de registrar outra mensagem. Quais as soluções possíveis?

O programa é o seguinte:

```
/*
 * Class do registo de mensagens
 */
import java.util.*;
public class RegistoDeMenssagem4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Bem vindo Utilizador"); // o número ou nome do utilizador 
        //Porque o registo de menssagem só é possível para números registados       
        System.out.println("Introduza o número da recarga");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Recarga = kb.nextInt(); // exception para o nùmero

        // Aqui irei introduzir o try-catch exceptions para cada input                                  
        System.out.println("Têm mais recarga para registar?");
        System.out.println("responda `S´ para continuar ou `N´ para terminar");
        String resposta;
        resposta = kb.nextLine();

        if (resposta.equals("s")) {
            System.out.println("Introduza o número da recarga");
            Scanner kb2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int MaisRecarga = kb.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Têm mais alguma recarga para registar?");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Obrigado, atê o próximo registo.");
            System.exit(0);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: pode ser só questão de maiúscula e minúscula

Comment: Substitua por `if (resposta.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))` se não faz diferença se é S maiúsculo ou minusculo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal fazer assim?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RegistoDeMensagem4 {

    private static int lerNumero(Scanner kb, String mensagem, String mensagemErro) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(mensagem);
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(mensagemErro);
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean lerSimNao(Scanner kb, String mensagem, String mensagemErro) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(mensagem);
            String x = kb.nextLine();
            if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) return true;
            if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) return false;
            System.out.println(mensagemErro);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Bem-vindo, utilizador.");
        boolean maisRecarga = true;
        while (maisRecarga) {
            int recarga = lerNumero(kb, "Introduza o número da recarga: ", "Isso que você digitou não era um número. Por favor, tente novamente.");
            System.out.println("Você digitou " + recarga + ".");
            maisRecarga = lerSimNao(kb, "Tem mais recarga para registar?\nResponda `S´ para continuar ou `N´ para terminar: ", "Era para você responder S ou N! Por favor, tente novamente.");
        }
        System.out.println("Obrigado, até o próximo registro.");
    }
}
```

Este programa tem o seguinte:

- O método `lerNumero`, que força a digitação de um número e insiste até que um número seja digitado.
- O método `lerSimNao`, que força a digitação de S ou N (maiúsculo ou minúsculo) e insiste até que um dos dois seja digitado.
- Utiliza apenas um `Scanner`.
- Utiliza `Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine())` ao invés de `kb.nextInt()` para ler números.
- Permite ao utilizador digitar quantas entradas ele quiser.
- Não utiliza `System.exit(0)` - Usar isso é em geral, uma má-prática de programação.

Eis um exemplo de entradas/saídas:

```
Bem-vindo, utilizador.
Introduza o número da recarga: 1234
Você digitou 1234.
Tem mais recarga para registar?
Responda `S´ para continuar ou `N´ para terminar: S
Introduza o número da recarga: Banana
Isso que você digitou não era um número. Por favor, tente novamente.
Introduza o número da recarga: 4321
Você digitou 4321.
Tem mais recarga para registar?
Responda `S´ para continuar ou `N´ para terminar: J
Era para você responder S ou N! Por favor, tente novamente.
Tem mais recarga para registar?
Responda `S´ para continuar ou `N´ para terminar: n
Obrigado, até o próximo registro.
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/pnIRp8)

Comment: Gostei da sua sugestão. entretanto, estou a compilar em cmd e tenho a seguinte mensagem de erro:

Comment: class RegistoDeMenssagem4 is public, should be declared in a file named RegistoDeMenssagem4.java

Comment: Devo referir ter gostado desta sugestão estando para adoptá-la.

Comment: Fui ao ideonee ví... mas em cmd o erro, cuja mensagem descrevi no comentário anterior, arrebenta na linha 3: public class RegistoDeMenssagem4

Comment: Victor Stafuta funcionou! agradecido. a sua versão do códico cumpre na perfeição a minha ideia.

Comment: @cambine Bem, que bom que funcionou para você. Esses erros que você teve é porque o nome da classe deve ser o mesmo do nome do arquivo se a classe for pública (mas se não for, isso não é necessário). No ideone, o arquivo que ele usa por debaixo dos panos se chama `Main.java`, e é por esse motivo que eu não coloquei o ´public´ na frente da declaração da classe no ideone. Já aqui na resposta, eu mantive o ´public´ porque é assim que vai ficar no seu código em seu computador.

Answer (score 9):

O problema é que você está usando o mesmo scanner do numero na sua resposta. Dessa forma ele sempre cairá no `else` pois já está com o valor do numero que digitou.

Crie um novo objeto do da classe `Scanner` pra ler sua resposta:

```
 String resposta;
 Scanner kc = new Scanner(System.in);
 resposta = kc.nextLine();
```

Comment: Bem notado! Nem tinha reparado que era o [velho problema do Scanner](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113834/28595)  +1

Comment: rs, eu demorei um tempinho pra notar também. Erros bobos são chatinhos de achar

Comment: Deram negativo mas a resposta resolve o problema da questão, agora se a forma parece pouco ortodoxa, o problema é mais da classe utilizada para leitura do que da resposta em si.

Answer (score 1):

"S" e "s" são Strings diferentes. `equalsIgnoreCase()` verifica se a `String` é igual, ignorando letras maiúsculas/minúsculas diferentes.

#### Exemplo

```
System.out.println("S".equals("s")); //false  

System.out.println("S".equalsIgnoreCase("s"));//true
```

Ou seja, você usar `equalsIgnoreCase()` quando pretende comparar uma `String`, sem fazer distinção entre letras maiúsculas ou minúsculas.

#### Detalhes

- [How to use equals( ) and equalsIgnoreCase( ) in Java](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=224)

Comment: Fiz a alteração para mas persiste o problema. Apenas executa a parte do códico correspondente ao "else" do mêtodo, mesmo depois da alteração.

Comment: @DiegoAugusto. A sua solução funciounou. O programa,depois de alterar o nome do segundo scanner para: Scanner kc = new Scanner(System.in);
 resposta = kc.nextLine();, executou como pretendo.