# Problema preenchimento de vetor com leitura de texto digitado

Tags: java, array, scanner

Estou fazendo um trabalhinho, que consta em cadastrar times e partidas de um campeonato de futebol. Ao compilar e executar o código, ele funciona, mas na parte em que eu vou cadastrar, ele pula campo.

exemplo:

[image: Esse é o probleminha]

Os códigos do programa:

CLASSE 1

```
public class Times {



    private Integer codigo;
    private String nome;
    private String data_fund;

    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Integer codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getdata_fund() {
        return data_fund;
    }

    public void setdata_fund(String data_fund) {
        this.data_fund = data_fund;
    }
}
```

CLASSE 2

```
public class Partidas {

    String TimeA;
    String TimeB;
    int Placar_timeA;
    int Placar_timeB;
    int pub_presente;


    public String getTimeA() {
        return TimeA;
        }

        public String TimeB() {
        return TimeB;
        }

        public int Placar_timeA() {
        return Placar_timeA;
        }

        public int Placar_timeB() {
            return Placar_timeB;
            }

        public int pub_presente() {
            return pub_presente;
            }

    public void setTimeA(String TimeA) {
        this.TimeA = TimeA;
        }

        public void setTimeB(String TimeB) {
        this.TimeB = TimeB;
        }

        public void setPlacar_timeA(int Placar_timeA) {
        this.Placar_timeA = Placar_timeA;
        }

        public void setPlacar_timeB(int Placar_timeB) {
            this.Placar_timeB = Placar_timeB;
            }

        public void setpub_presente(int pub_presente) {
            this.pub_presente = pub_presente;
            }

}
```

main

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);


        Times [] b ;
        b = new Times [20];

        Partidas [] p ;
        p = new Partidas [20];

        int op = 0;

        System.out.print("Digite a opção que deseja: \n");
        System.out.print("1 - Cadastrar Times. \n");
        System.out.print("2 - Cadastrar Partidas. \n");
        op = entrada.nextInt();

        if (op > 2 ){

            System.out.print("Opção INCORRETA! Inicie novamente \n");
        }

        if (op == 1) {

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){

            b[i] = new Times();

            System.out.print("Digite o código do Time: ");
            b[i].setCodigo(entrada.nextInt());


            System.out.print("Digite o nome do Time: ");
            b[i].setNome(entrada.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Digite a data de fundação do Time: ");
            b[i].setdata_fund(entrada.nextLine());

            System.out.print("\n\n"); 
        }}

        if ( op == 2){

            for (int i=0; i<5; i++){

                p[i] = new Partidas();

                System.out.print("Digite o TimeA:");
                p[i].setTimeA(entrada.nextLine());

                System.out.print("Digite o TimeB: ");
                p[i].setTimeB(entrada.nextLine());

                System.out.print("Digite o placar do TimeA: ");
                p[i].setPlacar_timeA(Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine()));

                System.out.print("Digite o placar do TimeB: ");
                p[i].setPlacar_timeB(Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine()));

                System.out.print("Digite o Publico Presente: ");
                p[i].setpub_presente(Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine()));

                System.out.print("\n\n"); 
            }}  

        }

  }
```

Comment: Tente por sua entrada em uma variavel local antes de usar os seus setTime(AB) `System.out.print("Digite o TimeA:"); string teste = entrada.nextLine();
    p[i].setTimeA(teste );`

Comment: Testei essa solução, mas continua no mesmo erro. Ele apresenta esse erro na primeira execução do "for", e apenas com string. Na segunda execução em diante fica normal.

Comment: Ou duplicada desta: [Como usar o scanner do Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30642/28595)