# JAVA Aplicação pula comandos

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Quando escolho o caso 1, ele funciona ok. Mas se escolher essa opção de novo, o console mostra o menu, como se a opção não funcionasse.

Tem algum erro visível nesse código?

```
{
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Banking {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ContaBancaria[] conta = new ContaBancaria[10];

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            conta[i] = new ContaBancaria();
        }

        System.out.println("Bem vindo!");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int op1 = -1;

        while (op1 != 3){
            System.out.println("Escolha a operacao desejada: \n" + " 1 - Criar nova conta\n"
                    + " 2 - Acessar minha conta\n" + " 3 - Cancelar operacao");
            op1 = sc.nextInt();

            switch (op1){
            case 1:
                for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
                    if (conta[i].cliente == ""){
                        System.out.println("Nome do cliente: ");
                        sc.nextLine();
                        conta[i].cliente = sc.nextLine();
                        conta[i].id = i+1;
                        System.out.println("Dados da sua conta: ");
                        System.out.println("Cliente: "+conta[i].getCliente());
                        System.out.println("Numero de identificacao da conta: "+conta[i].getId());
                        System.out.println("Saldo: R$"+conta[i].getSaldoInicial());
                    }
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Digite o numero de identificacao da conta: ");
                int nid = sc.nextInt();
                if(nid <= 0 || nid > 10){
                    System.out.println("Numero de conta invalido.\n");
                    break;
                }
                for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
                    if(conta[i].getId() == nid){
                        System.out.println("Bem vindo!\nConfirme os dados de sua conta: ");
                        System.out.println("Cliente: "+conta[i].getCliente());
                        System.out.println("Numero de identificacao da conta: "+conta[i].getId());
                        System.out.println("Saldo: R$"+conta[i].getSaldoInicial());
                    }

                    int op2 = -1;
                    while (op2 != 5) {
                        System.out.println("Entre com a operacao que desejada: \n" + " 1 - Sacar uma quantia \n"
                                + " 2 - Depositar uma quantia \n" + " 3 - Alterar saldo minimo \n" + " 4 - Obter saldo \n"
                                + " 5 - Cancelar operacao");
                        op2 = sc.nextInt();
                        switch (op2) {
                        case 1:
                            System.out.print("Entre com o valor para sacar: ");
                            float valorSaque = sc.nextFloat();
                            conta[i].Sacar(valorSaque);
                                break;
                        case 2:
                            System.out.print("Entre com o valor para depositar: ");
                            float valorDeposito = sc.nextFloat();
                            conta[i].Depositar(valorDeposito);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            System.out.print("Entre com o valor para saldo minimo: ");
                            float valorSaldo = sc.nextFloat();
                            conta[i].AlterarSaldoMinimo(valorSaldo);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            System.out.println("Saldo: " + conta[i].ConsultarSaldo());
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            System.out.println("Obrigado por usar nossos servicos.\nAte breve.");
                            System.exit(0);
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("OPERACAO INCORRETA");
                        } //fim switch
                    } //fim while
                } //fim for
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Obrigado por usar nossos servicos.\nAte breve!");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("OPERACAO INCORRETA");
    } //fim switch
    } //fim while
        sc.close();
} //fim main
} //fim classe
}
```

Comment: Relacionada: [Como usar o scanner do Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30642/28595)

Comment: Tentei inserir o sc.nextLine(); mas não funcionou :/

Comment: Fabiola, veja a resposta do Math no segundo link e faça como ele explicou, isso irá resolver o problema.

Comment: Ainda nao funciona.