# Campo int como string

Tags: java, cast, entrada-de-dados

Estou trabalhando em um código para um trabalho de faculdade, mas estou tendo problemas, apesar da "casa" estar configurada para INT, o netbeans continua a apresentar:

> "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int"

abaixo segue o código, desde de já, muito obrigado!

```
package tictactoe;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author Leonardo
 */
public class Main {

    private static String tipoJogo;
    private static Random rand = new Random();
    private static int  n = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
    private static int casa;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner carrega = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Bem vindo!");
        System.out.println("Insira o tipo de Jogo");
        tipoJogo = carrega.next();

        int valida = 0,
                jogadas = 0;

        jogo jogo = new jogo();


        switch (tipoJogo) {

            case "humano":

                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("teste teste");

                    do {
                        jogo.varTabu();
                        System.out.printf("Primeiro Jogador, ensira sua "
                                + "jogada nas casas de 1 a 9 \n\r");
                        casa = carrega.next();
                        while (!jogo.ok(casa)) {
                            System.out.print("Casa já escolhida, tente outra!");
                            System.out.printf("Primeiro Jogador, ensira sua "
                                    + "jogada nas casas de 1 a 9");
                            casa = carrega.next();
                            valida = 0;

                        }
                        jogo.jogada(casa, "O");
                        valida = 1;

                    } while (valida == 0);
                    jogadas++;
                    valida = 0;
                    if (!jogo.ganhador(jogadas).equals("null")) {
                        break;
                    }
                    do {
                        jogo.varTabu();
                        System.out.printf("Segundo Jogador, ensira sua "
                                + "jogada  nas casas de 1 a 9\n\r");
                        casa = carrega.next();
                        while (!jogo.ok(casa)) {
                            System.out.print("Casa já escolhida, tente outra!");
                            System.out.printf("Segundo Jogador, ensira sua "
                                    + "jogada /n/r nas casas de 1 a 9");
                            casa = carrega.next();
                            valida = 0;

                        }
                        jogo.jogada(casa, "X");
                        valida = 1;

                    } while (valida == 0);
                    jogadas++;
                    valida = 0;
                    if (!jogo.ganhador(jogadas).equals("null")) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                jogo.varTabu();
                System.out.printf("O campeão foi o " + jogo.ganhador(jogadas));
                break;
            case "cFacil":

                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("teste teste");

                    do {
                        jogo.varTabu();
                        System.out.printf("Primeiro Jogador, ensira sua "
                                + "jogada nas casas de 1 a 9 \n\r");
                        casa = carrega.next();
                        while (!jogo.ok(casa)) {
                            System.out.print("Casa já escolhida, tente outra!");
                            System.out.printf("Primeiro Jogador, ensira sua "
                                    + "jogada nas casas de 1 a 9");
                            casa = carrega.next();
                            valida = 0;

                        }
                        jogo.jogada(casa, "O");
                        valida = 1;

                    } while (valida == 0);
                    jogadas++;
                    valida = 0;
                    if (!jogo.ganhador(jogadas).equals("null")) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("pudim");

                    break;
                }
                /* inicio parte computador           
                //////////////////////////////////
                //////////////////////////////////
                //////////////////////////////////
                /////////////////////////////////                
                 */
                do {
                    jogo.varTabu();

                    System.out.printf("Segundo Jogador, ensira sua "
                            + "jogada  nas casas de 1 a 9\n\r");
                    n = carrega.next();
                    while (!jogo.ok(casa)) {
                        System.out.print("Casa já escolhida, tente outra!");
                        System.out.printf("Segundo Jogador, ensira sua "
                                + "jogada /n/r nas casas de 1 a 9");
                        casa = carrega.next();
                        valida = 0;

                    }
                    jogo.jogada(casa, "X");
                    valida = 1;

                } while (valida == 0);
                jogadas++;
                valida = 0;
                if (!jogo.ganhador(jogadas).equals("null")) {
                    break;
                }
                break;
        }
        jogo.varTabu();
        System.out.printf("O campeão foi o " + jogo.ganhador(jogadas));

    }
}
```

Comment: Deve ser na hora de pegar o valor do input que vem como string. Tenta dá um Integer.parseInt(casa) para ver se funciona.

Comment: poderia me dizer em qual parte do código devo inserir: "Integer.parseInt(casa)", estou um pouco perdido.

Comment: Já resolvido na resposta abaixo :D .

Answer (score 3):

O método `next()` do Scanner retorna uma string delimitada até o primeiro espaço. Logo, você não pode atribuir essa captura de entrada de dados em String a uma variável int.

Altere todos os:

```
casa = carrega.next();
```

para:

```
casa = carrega.nextInt();
```

A linha `n = carrega.next();` provavelmente dará este mesmo problema, pois `n` foi declarado como int, faça a mesma alteração para resolver o problema.

Como há um loop de captura de dados, é bem provável que você tenha problemas com o vazamento de uma quebra de linha desta chamada, aproveite e dê uma lida [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30642/como-usar-o-scanner-do-java), caso isso ocorra.

**Referências para leitura:**

[Classe Scanner(Documentação)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html])

[Entrada de Dados: Classe Scanner](http://www.devmedia.com.br/entrada-de-dados-classe-scanner/21366)

Comment: Diegofm, excelente isso realmente resolveu 90% do problema, mas o campo "casa" da parte "while (!jogo.ok(casa))" continua dando problema. http://i.stack.imgur.com/gW7Mp.png

Comment: @LeonardoLemgruber bom, ai parece ser outro problema diferente da pergunta, teria que adicionar esse método `jogo.ok()` para analisar, mas sugiro que crie outra pergunta com a nova duvida, para não invalidar a resposta. Você pode clicar no `v` para aceitar esta resposta e dar por resolvido o problema de cast e partir para o novo problema :)

Comment: @LeonardoLemgruber a resposta resolveu o problema do campo int e string?