# Linha de código ignorada

Tags: java, entrada-de-dados

A linha marcada com `/*ISSO AQUI*/` está sendo ignorada, ou seja, o nome para o segundo empregado não é lido, apenas o sobrenome.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Employee Empregado1 = new Employee();
    Employee Empregado2 = new Employee();

    System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
    String nome = input.nextLine();
    Empregado1.setName(nome);

    System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
    String sobreNome = input.nextLine();
    Empregado1.setLastName(sobreNome);

    System.out.print("Enter you salary: ");
    double salario = input.nextDouble();
    Empregado1.setSalary(salario);

    double novoSalario = Empregado1.getSalary() + (0.10*Empregado1.getSalary());

    Empregado1.setSalary(novoSalario);
    Empregado1.showEmployee();

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    System.out.print("\n\nEnter your name: ");
    /*ISSO AQUI*/ nome = input.nextLine(); /*ISSO AQUI*/
    Empregado2.setName(nome);

    System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
    sobreNome = input.nextLine();
    Empregado2.setLastName(sobreNome);

    System.out.print("Enter you salary: ");
    salario = input.nextDouble();
    Empregado2.setSalary(salario);

    novoSalario = Empregado2.getSalary() + (0.10*Empregado2.getSalary());

    Empregado2.setSalary(novoSalario);
    Empregado2.showEmployee();

    input.close();
}

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isto ocorre por causa de uma particularidade dos métodos da classe  [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Quando você faz esta chamada:

```
System.out.print("Enter you salary: ");
double salario = input.nextDouble();
```

Ao dar o <kbd>enter</kbd>, há uma quebra de linha que não é capturada pelo `nextDouble()`. Porém, ao fazer isso:

```
System.out.print("\n\nEnter your name: ");
nome = input.nextLine(); /*ISSO AQUI*/
```

o `nextLine()` pegará a string até a quebra de linha ocorrer. E como já há uma quebra de linha não capturada, este método acaba consumindo essa quebra de linha e passando o código em diante.

Uma solução seria capturar a quebra de linha antes de chegar ai, adicionando um simples `input.nextLine()` logo após o `nextDouble()`.

```
System.out.print("Enter you salary: ");
double salario = input.nextDouble();
input.nextLine();
Empregado1.setSalary(salario);
```

Lembrando que esse problema ocorrerá sempre que você efetuar captura de dados primitivos com captura de string através do `nextLine()`, e não somente como o `nextDouble()`.

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30652/28595) é dada uma solução melhor para lidar com este problema, apesar de parecer um pouco mais trabalhosa de se implementar.

Answer (score 3):

Boa tarde,

O causador está nesta linha:

```
 double salario = input.nextDouble();
```

A função lê apenas até o próximo token e não a linha inteira, então quando você chama o `nome = input.nextLine();` ele termina de ler a linha.

Você pode usar mais um `input.nextLine();` para ler a linha anterior, sem atribuir a nada, ou pode tentar assim:

```
//tente substituir
double salario = input.nextDouble();
// por
double salario = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());
```

Comment: Na verdade o que o nextdouble não lê é a quebra de linha deixada pelo enter, e como o nextLine consome a string até houver uma quebra de linha, ele acaba consumindo a quebra de linha deixada pelo nextdouble.

Comment: Obrigado pela correção.

Answer (score 2):

Isso é porque o nextDouble não consome o último caractere de nova linha de sua entrada e, portanto, a nova linha é consumido na próxima chamada, uma solução é utilizar o `next()` ao invés do `nextLine()`, desta forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Employee Empregado1 = new Employee();
    Employee Empregado2 = new Employee();

    System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
    String nome = input.next();
    Empregado1.setName(nome);

    System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
    String sobreNome = input.next();
    Empregado1.setLastName(sobreNome);

    System.out.print("Enter you salary: ");
    double salario = input.nextDouble();
    Empregado1.setSalary(salario);

    double novoSalario = Empregado1.getSalary() + (0.10 * Empregado1.getSalary());

    Empregado1.setSalary(novoSalario);
    Empregado1.showEmployee();

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    System.out.print("\n\nEnter your name: ");
    /* ISSO AQUI */ nome = input.next(); /* ISSO AQUI */
    Empregado2.setName(nome);

    System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
    sobreNome = input.next();
    Empregado2.setLastName(sobreNome);

    System.out.print("Enter you salary: ");
    salario = input.nextDouble();
    Empregado2.setSalary(salario);

    novoSalario = Empregado2.getSalary() + (0.10 * Empregado2.getSalary());

    Empregado2.setSalary(novoSalario);
    Empregado2.showEmployee();

    input.close();
}
```