# Erro NoSuchElementException ao capturar entrada de dados com Scanner

Tags: java, scanner, entrada-de-dados

Estou tendo problemas com entradas de dados utilizando o Scanner com o JOptionPane funciona de boa.

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>
>   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
>   at pkgClientesPedidosDiogoVinicius.TesteClientesPedidos.menu(TesteClientesPedidos.java:43)
>   at pkgClientesPedidosDiogoVinicius.TesteClientesPedidos.main(TesteClientesPedidos.java:18)
> ```

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class TesteClientesPedidos {

    static int opcao;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        menu();

    }

    static void menu() throws IOException {

        Scanner leitura = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("PROGRAMA CLIENTES/PEDIDOS - OPÇÕES\n");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------\n");
            System.out.println("1  - Cadastrar Gerente\n");
            System.out.println("2  - Cadastrar Vendedor\n");
            System.out.println("3  - Cadastrar Técnico\n");
            System.out.println("4  - Mostrar dados dos funcionarios(Gerente/Vendedor/Técnico\n");
            System.out.println("5  - Cadastrar Item de Pedido\n");
            System.out.println("6  - Cadastrar Pedido\n");
            System.out.println("7  - Mostrar Dados de Pedido e Item de Pedido\n");
            System.out.println("8  - Cadastrar Gerente Administrativo\n");
            System.out.println("9  - Cadastrar Gerente Financeiro\n");
            System.out.println("10 - Mostrar dados de Gerente Administrativo e Financeiro\n");
            System.out.println("11 - Mostrar cálculo do salário para cada funcionario (Gerente/Vendedor/Técnico\n");
            System.out.println("12 - Sobre\n");
            System.out.println("13 - Encerrar programa\n");

            System.out.println("Informe a opção:");
            opcao = leitura.nextInt();
            switch (opcao) {
            case 1:
                cadastrarGerente();
                System.out.println(">>PROGRAMA");
                break;
            case 13:
                System.out.println(">>PROGRAMA FINALIZADO");
                break;
            }

        } while (opcao != 13);
        leitura.close();
    }

    public static void cadastrarGerente() {

        String nome;
        int matricula;
        String telefone;
        String email;
        String cidade;
        String estado;
        double salario;
        double taxaVenda;

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("CADASTRAR GERENTE\n");
        System.out.println("Nome:........:");
        nome = entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Matricula:...:");
        matricula = entrada.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Telefone:....:");
        telefone = entrada.next();

        System.out.println("Cidade:......:");
        cidade = entrada.nextLine();
        entrada.next();

        System.out.println("E-mail:......:");
        email = entrada.nextLine();
        entrada.next();

        System.out.println("Salário:.....:");
        salario = entrada.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Estado:......:");
        estado = entrada.nextLine();
        entrada.next();

        Gerente g1 = new Gerente(nome, matricula, telefone, email, cidade, estado, salario);

        try {
            System.out.println("Taxa Venda:..:");
            taxaVenda = entrada.nextDouble();
            g1.setTaxaVenda(taxaVenda);

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        entrada.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que você está manipulando duas variáveis para entrada de dados, e está fechando a segunda. Só que ao fazer `entrada.close();`, você está encerrando a entrada de dados(o `System.in`) e não apenas a variável.

Com isso, ao tentar retornar para o menu, estoura esta exceção na linha `opcao = leitura.nextInt();`, pois você já encerrou o `System.in`, que o responsável pelas entrada de dados em java de forma global, inclusive na variável `leitura`, aberta no seu main.

Uma das soluções possiveis sem alterar demais o código é trabalhar apenas com uma variavel Scanner, e usar ela para capturar todas as entradas desta classe:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TesteClientesPedidos {

    static int opcao;
    static Scanner leitura = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        menu();

    }

    static void menu() throws IOException {

        do {
            System.out.println("PROGRAMA CLIENTES/PEDIDOS - OPÇÕES\n");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------\n");
            System.out.println("1  - Cadastrar Gerente\n");
            System.out.println("2  - Cadastrar Vendedor\n");
            System.out.println("3  - Cadastrar Técnico\n");
            System.out.println("4  - Mostrar dados dos funcionarios(Gerente/Vendedor/Técnico\n");
            System.out.println("5  - Cadastrar Item de Pedido\n");
            System.out.println("6  - Cadastrar Pedido\n");
            System.out.println("7  - Mostrar Dados de Pedido e Item de Pedido\n");
            System.out.println("8  - Cadastrar Gerente Administrativo\n");
            System.out.println("9  - Cadastrar Gerente Financeiro\n");
            System.out.println("10 - Mostrar dados de Gerente Administrativo e Financeiro\n");
            System.out.println("11 - Mostrar cálculo do salário para cada funcionario (Gerente/Vendedor/Técnico\n");
            System.out.println("12 - Sobre\n");
            System.out.println("13 - Encerrar programa\n");

            System.out.println("Informe a opção:");
            opcao = leitura.nextInt();
            leitura.nextLine();
            switch (opcao) {
            case 1:
                cadastrarGerente();
                System.out.println(">>PROGRAMA");
                break;
            case 13:
                System.out.println(">>PROGRAMA FINALIZADO");
                break;
            }

        } while (opcao != 13);
        leitura.close();
    }

    public static void cadastrarGerente() {

        String nome;
        int matricula;
        String telefone;
        String email;
        String cidade;
        String estado;
        double salario;
        double taxaVenda;

        System.out.println("CADASTRAR GERENTE\n");
        System.out.println("Nome:........:");
        nome = leitura.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Matricula:...:");
        matricula = leitura.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Telefone:....:");
        telefone = leitura.next();

        System.out.println("Cidade:......:");
        cidade = leitura.nextLine();
        leitura.next();

        System.out.println("E-mail:......:");
        email = leitura.nextLine();
        leitura.next();

        System.out.println("Salário:.....:");
        salario = leitura.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Estado:......:");
        estado = leitura.nextLine();
        leitura.next();

        Gerente g1 = new Gerente(nome, matricula, telefone, email, cidade, estado, salario);

        try {
            System.out.println("Taxa Venda:..:");
            taxaVenda = leitura.nextDouble();
            g1.setTaxaVenda(taxaVenda);

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Perceba que tem um `leitura.nextLine()` logo após pegar a opção, e isso é para não deixar escapar o espaço e pular uma das entradas de dado, caso a opção escolhida seja 1. Mas essa não é a solução recomendada, recomendo que dê uma lida [**nesta resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30652/28595), que tem uma orientação melhor de como evitar esse tipo de escape.

Answer (score -1):

Pra quem ainda está com o problema ainda, apenas precisa limpar o Scanner antes de usá-lo novamente com um

`scanner.clear()`

antes de usar ou no fim do while.

Answer (score -1):

Sei que o tópico é velho mas pode ser que seja útil para alguém...
Estava com o mesmo problema.
Resolvi instanciando uma variável Scanner no início da classe principal, reutilizando dentro dos métodos e só fechando no final da classe.

No seu caso,

```
public class TesteClientesPedidos {

    static int opcao;
    static Scanner leitura = new Scanner(System.in);
.
.
.
.
.
    leitura.close();
}
```