# Criar mais de uma variável usando o comando scanner

Tags: java, scanner

Dei uma procurada pelo google porém não consegui uma resposta que iluminasse minha cabeça, estou começando a estudar java e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Criar um programa Java que leia do teclado 10 nomes e seus salários e depois mostre o nome de quem tem o maior e o menor salário.

Lembrando que eu ainda não fiz a parte do if no final para comparar, minha dúvida mesmo é como salvar diferentes variáveis usando o scanner.

Obriagdo desde já:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String nome1;
    int salario1;
    int contador = 0;


    while (contador <= 15) {
        System.out.println(" Qual o seu nome?");
        Scanner nome = new Scanner(System.in);
        nome1 = nome.next();
        System.out.println(" Qual o seu salário?");
        Scanner salario = new Scanner(System.in);
        salario1 = salario.nextInt();


        contador = (contador + 1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Recomendado a leitura https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209571/erro-nosuchelementexception-ao-capturar-entrada-de-dados-com-scanner/209580#209580

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o Scanner retorna um valor String, se vc quer salvar vários valores pode usar um ArrayList para salvar todos os nomes e outro para salvar os salários mais se quiser fazer do jeito que vc fez pode fazer assim:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String nome;
    int salario;
    int contador = 0;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nomeMaior = null;
    String nomeMenor = null;
    int salarioMaior = 0;
    int salarioMenor = 0;

    while (contador < 10) {
        System.out.println("Qual seu nome? ");
        nome = s.next();
        //System.out.println(nome);
        System.out.println("Qual seu salário? ");
        salario = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
        //System.out.println(salario);

                    // vc tem que testa toda vez que pedir um nome e salario novo
                    // enquanto tiver mais de um nome                        

        if (contador > 0) {
            if (salario > salarioMaior) {
                nomeMaior = nome;
                salarioMaior = salario;
            } else if (salario < salarioMenor) {
                nomeMenor = nome;
                salarioMenor = salario;
            }
        } else {
            nomeMaior = nome;
            nomeMenor = nome;
            salarioMaior = salario;
            salarioMenor = salario;
        }

        contador+=1;
    }
    System.out.println("Maior : " + nomeMaior + " " + salarioMaior);
    System.out.println("Menor : " + nomeMenor + " " + salarioMenor);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, estava com esta ideia na cabeça, mas não estava conseguindo escrever.  Obrigado!