# Estou tendo um problema com a leitura de uma variavel do tipo string em java

Tags: java

Criei uma variável do tipo string e ela não esta lendo uma frase com quebra de linha, esta simplesmente pulando, em java existe um modo de limpar buff como C ou alguma coisa qu possa fazer?

trecho do codigo:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String nome;
nome = sc.next();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pra ler com quebra de linha você tem que utilizar [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String nome;
nome = sc.nextLine();
```

Só tome cuidado ao misturar a leitura de Strings com leitura de tipos primitivos numéricos com essa classe, devido ao [**vazamento da quebra de linha**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30642/28595).