# Como fazer um programa em Java para verificar se três cartas de um baralho convencional são uma trinca?

Tags: java, string, char

Tenho a seguinte tarefa para a faculdade:

> 27. Faça um programa que leia 3 cartas (valor e naipe) de um baralho, verifique
>     e escreva se as três cartas formam uma trinca. Para ser uma trinca, os
>     valores devem ser iguais, mas os naipes diferentes.

Por enquanto, aprendemos apenas programas sequenciais e programas com seleção (if... else, switch... case). Então, esse programa precisa ser resolvido utilizando esses recursos. Acredito que desse para resolver utilizando um array, mas ainda não aprendemos. Consegui chegar ao seguinte código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AppEx27
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String carta1;
        String carta2;
        String carta3;
        
        char valor1;
        char valor2;
        char valor3;
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Insira sua primeira carta:");
        carta1 = in.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Insira sua segunda carta:");
        carta2 = in.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Insira sua terceira carta:");
        carta3 = in.nextLine();
        
        int tamanhoCarta1 = carta1.length();
        int tamanhoCarta2 = carta2.length();
        int tamanhoCarta3 = carta3.length();
        
        if(tamanhoCarta1 == 2){
            valor1 = carta1.charAt(0);
            char naipe1 = carta1.charAt(1);
        }
        else if (tamanhoCarta1 == 3){
            String valor13 = "10";
            char naipe1 = carta1.charAt(2);
        }
        
        if(tamanhoCarta2 == 2){
            valor2 = carta2.charAt(0);
            char naipe2 = carta2.charAt(1);
        }
        else if (tamanhoCarta2 == 3){
            String valor23 = "10";
            char naipe2 = carta2.charAt(2);
        }
        
        if(tamanhoCarta3 == 2){
            valor3 = carta3.charAt(0);
            char naipe3 = carta3.charAt(1);
        }
        else if (tamanhoCarta3 == 3){
            String valor33 = "10";
            char naipe3 = carta3.charAt(2);
        }
```

Minha ideia era que o usuário entrasse as três cartas em formato de string ("AC" para ás de copas, "2P" para dois de paus e "10E" para dez de espadas, por exemplo) e, internamente, o programa separasse o valor e o naipe da carta (para "AC", valor = 'A' e naipe = 'C'). Depois, bastaria comparar se os valores das três cartas são iguais (e se os naipes são diferentes). O problema é que, para separar o valor da carta do naipe dela, não é simplesmente usar um método `.charAt(0)` para obter o 'A' (valor) e um `.chartAt(1)` para obter o 'C' (naipe) porque, caso o usuário insira alguma carta com valor 10, como "10P" (dez de paus), o programa não irá dar certo. Pensei, então, em usar a função `.length()` para descobrir se o usuário entrou alguma carta com valor 10 (se o tamanho da string for 3, é porque a carta tem valor 10) e, então, utilizar uma abordagem para o caso de o valor ser composto por apenas um caractere (1 a 9 ou A, J, Q ou K) e outra abordagem diferente para caso o valor seja composto por dois caracteres (10). Porém, me sinto perdido agora e não sei como continuar esse código.

Answer (score -4):

Creio que o codigo ta auto-explicativo, porém vou dar uma geral. Precisamos pegar os dados do usuário e colocar em variáveis para todas as cartas. Tem meios mais eficientes de fazer isso, porém você so pode usar o básico.

Quando pegamos cada dado, temos que verificar as regras:

1. Os naipes têm que ser diferentes

   - Pego cada valor e comparo com o outro para verificar se são iguais
   - Junto tudo num boolean invertendo cada resultado, se ao menos um naipe for igual, a variável principal que armazena a regra fica falsa
2. Os valores têm que ser iguais

   - Pego cada valor e comparo com o outro para verificar se são iguais
   - Junto tudo num boolean da regra, se ao menos um for diferente, a regra fica falsa

Depois juntos toda as regras e verifico se todas foram bem atendidas.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // criando campo para cada naipe de carta
    String naipeCarta1;
    String naipeCarta2;
    String naipeCarta3;

    // criando campo para cada valor de carta
    int valorCarta1;
    int valorCarta2;
    int valorCarta3;

    

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Insira sua naipe da 1º carta:");
    naipeCarta1 = in.next(); // Atribuindo o naipe da 1º carta

    System.out.println("Agora insira o valor dela:");
    valorCarta1 = in.nextInt(); // Atribuindo o valor da 1º carta

    System.out.println("Insira sua naipe da 2º carta:");
    naipeCarta2 = in.next(); // Atribuindo o naipe da 2º carta

    System.out.println("Agora insira o valor dela:");
    valorCarta2 = in.nextInt(); // Atribuindo o valor da 1º carta

    System.out.println("Insira sua naipe da 3º carta:");
    naipeCarta3 = in.next(); // Atribuindo o naipe da 3º carta

    System.out.println("Agora insira o valor dela:");
    valorCarta3 = in.nextInt(); // Atribuindo o valor da 1º carta

    // Chegou a hora de verificar cada instrução

    // A 1º é verificar se os naipes são diferentes, com isso pego cada variavel atribuida e uso a função primitiva equals, que verifica se são iguais
    //O equals retorna true se for igual, então eu quero saber se é diferente, logo ponho uma ! antes para "inverter" o valor do booleano

    boolean naipesSaoDiferentes = !naipeCarta1.equals(naipeCarta2) && !naipeCarta1.equals(naipeCarta3) && !naipeCarta2.equals(naipeCarta3);

    // A 2º é verificar se os valores das cartão são iguais
    // Então so colocar um igual para cada afirmação, ou seja, verificar se o valor da 1º carta é igual da 2º e da 3º
    boolean valoresSaoIguais = valorCarta1 == valorCarta2 && valorCarta1 == valorCarta3;

    System.out.print("Resultado:");

    //Aqui so vejo se as regras preditas atenderam ao requisito ( booleano é true, se for o caso)
    if (naipesSaoDiferentes && valoresSaoIguais)
        System.out.println(" é uma trinca!");
    else // Se não for, so mosro dizendo que não é uma trinca, porque não atendeu as regras
        System.out.println(" não é uma trinca");
}
```

}

Comment: Seu código tem problemas de execução. Conforme problema já explicado [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30642/164151), algumas leituras do usuário não serão executadas no teu codigo.

Comment: Aproveito a oportunidade para sugerir que, além da correção do erro no codigo, também edite sua pergunta, adicionando explicações ao usuário a respeito da criação da lógica do problema dele, para que ele tenha o aprendizado e não somente um código para copiar.

Comment: A edição melhorou muito a resposta, porém, as alterações para next ainda gerarão problemas. Recomendo que leia  [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30652/164151) que está no link que já mandei, alterar para `next()` gera outro problema  semelhante.